# Loading an external Javascript file in Vue.js

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

How can I include and initialize a javascript file `mymain.min.js`that is in my assets folder within my project using VueJs with webpack?

**Webpack.base.conf**

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': resolve('src'),
      'sauJs': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/assets/mymain.min.js'),
    }
  },
```

I have also tried adding `<script src="src/assets/mymain.min.js"></script>` to my index.html page however I get `Cannot GET /src/assets/mymain.min.js`

Comment: So there is no option to pull your external file from `NPM`, pull it in locally, use it as a script tag before your main file or weave it into your code(if it is small)? Webpack is not meant to pull in external files I am sure you can abuse it to do so, but I am also sure there probably is a better way.

Comment: I have tried to add this to index.html but am getting Cannot GET /src/assets/mymain.min.js

Comment: Which one of the 4 methods I just described have you tried?

Comment: 1. Its not an npm package but just a js file in my assets folder. 2.pull it in locally? 3 I Used it as a script tag in index.html but am getting "cannot get" 4. Its too large to weave it in.

Comment: Updated question. It is not an npm but a js file that is in my assets folder inside my project

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding how this works. Resolve does not actually bundle your javascript code, it makes sure that when you do something like `require('@/test')` that it will resolve to `require('src/test')`. This is not where you pull in your javascript. Your webpack config should have an `entry` property with your main javascript file. That is where you pull in your code. Optionally you can specify multiple entry points or bundle multiple files into one without import.

Comment: Thanks, Yes indeed I am misunderstanding how this works. could you update this with a working answer to show?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are misunderstand what resolve actually does. This is not where you put the Javascript code that would actually bundle together.

When you specify a resolve alias like so:

```
'@': resolve('src'),
```

It will make sure that when you use:

```
require('@/test')
```

It will get resolved to:

```
require('src/test')
```

This is helpful to prevent relatives paths all over the place and you can also alias paths that are longer to prevent retyping them all the type.

Your webpack file should have an `entry` property that specifies your main `uncompiled` javascript file.

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './example/main.js',
}
```

In your `main.js` file you can import the javascript file that you want to include in your bundle.

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
// Or:
const vue = require('vue')
// Or(.js extension can be omitted):
import MyFile from './src/MyFile.js'
```

The other approach is to specify another `entry` property, something I have not done personally.

This is way out of the scope of this answer though. If you want more information you should check out the documentation:

https://webpack.js.org/concepts/

Alternatively this could make your life easier if you don't want to deal with the intricacies:

https://symfony.com/blog/introducing-webpack-encore-for-asset-management

Or:

https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix

Comment: Thanks, I used const SauJs = require('./assets/main') and Vue.use(SauJs) in my main.js file and added the file in .eslintignore